# Vue 2.0 & Rails 5: Declarative Rendering not Reactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, declarative

I am currently walking through the Vue guide with a Rails 5 app and found that I can update my Vue js object, but the DOM is not as described in the [**Declarative Rendering**](https://vuejs.org/guide/#Declarative-Rendering) section..

> The data and the DOM are now linked, and everything is now reactive. How do we know? Just open up your browser’s JavaScript console and set app.message to a different value. You should see the rendered example above update accordingly.

I am using the `gem 'vuejs'` found here:
https://github.com/ytbryan/vuejs

*application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require vue2
//= require vue-router2
//= require vue-validator
//= require vuex
//= require_tree .
```

*home.html.haml*

```
#app
  %div
   {{ message }}
```

*main.coffee*

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->

   app = new Vue
     el: '#app'
     data: 
       message: 'Vue initialized!'
```

Chrome tools js console..
`app.message = 'Should update to this'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this had to do with how coffeescript compiles it's variables. It inserts `var` to all variables not allowing them to be accessible by the global namespace. All that is required is the `app` to be a property of the `window` object.

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->

   window.app = new Vue
    el: '#app'
    data: 
      message: 'Vue initialized!'
```